# Trying to play only one audio file at a time using mediaPlayer and if/else

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I've tried to follow the other questions, but I don't think that they are what I am looking for.

Here's my java: http://pastie.org/private/psy2nnys8i0ajz4i8qfw

I know I am opening multiple instances of mp, so I try to detect if one is playing, and stop it on lines 34-39, but it still overlaps

please advise. I tried singleton's - but that didn't work, I also tried to use one mediaplayer instance and set the datasource, but couldnt figure out how to pass the R.raw.clipname to it.

Thanks!

Comment: @Harry I was just about to write that, so +1 for soundpool :)

Comment: @keyser5053 I think soundpool would be an issue because of the size of the files - they range from 800kb to 1mb, and I read that soundpool works best for smaller files then what I use?

Comment: I don't know. It might be an issue, but if it's easy to test, go ahead and do so. Otherwise, all I can suggest is debugging like crazy...(sry).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be somehow hard to try and debug/trace your code. But I can give you a solution to open a raw resource in your `MediaPlayer`, which will also make your code more robust and simple :

```
MediaPlayer player=new MediaPlayer();
player.setDataSource(
    getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.clip1).getFileDescriptor());
```

Answer (score 0):

USE THIS ONE:

@Override

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
     switch (event.getAction()) {
     case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP://int end
         pv.stop();
         pv.reset();
         pv=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.slot);
         Toast.makeText(this,"stop",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         break;
     case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN://in start
         pv.start();
         Toast.makeText(this,"play",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         break;
     default:
         break;
     }
     return false;
 }
```